# Unexpected token error when using ionic/cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am following trying to set up a barcode scanner using the following -
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

This is my code -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) { 

}

this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {

console.log(barcodeData);

}, (err) => {

});
}
```

When I run it, I get an error saying

```
Typescript Error
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, as I have followed the code given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the code inside a constructor or a function.

```
ScanCode() : any{
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    console.log(barcodeData);
    }, (err) => {
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. The errors are gone, but now when I run the code nothing happens.
I set a button up in the view -
    <button ion-button (click)="ScanCode()">Scan Barcode</button>

When I click on the button, nothing happens. Nothing runs etc. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to call the function ScanCode() from your template wherever its needed. mark if the answer helped

Comment: I think you replied before my edit. I tried that, no errors now. But nothing happens, camera doesnt open etc

Comment: you need to add a debugger and see what happens

Comment: Is this where I need to use an emulator?
I have had so many issues. Ive installed android studio, but AVD hasnt installed. Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no success.
When I run - ionic cordova emulate android
I get an error telling me to run appdata\local\android\sdk\tools\android.bat to create AVDs, but I click this and a console window flicks on and off

Comment: I have figured out how to use my device along with chrome dev-tools.
The error I am getting when I click the scan barcode button is -

BarcodeScanner.scan, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

I think this is the same as another error I had when trying a different solution. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling cordova, with no success. If I type cordova -v into the command line it returns saying version 8.0.0 is installed.

Comment: Ahh seem to have it working now. I need to rebuild after every change made in the code. And running -
ionic cordova run android -l
Doesnt work, I have to lose the -l